# Are YouTube video comments indexed by search engines?

Tags: seo

Are YouTube video comments indexed by search engines such as Google - yahoo - bing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a website you control.

Comment: Find a trending/popular YouTube video, pick a random comment, search for random comment in Google... does it return the YouTube video? **A. YES**. For example: https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=yiUHW4XtHcHD6QSc3pigCw&q=%22This+video+is+gonna+get+you+to+one+billion+views+with+just+81+videos%22&oq=%22This+video+is+gonna+get+you+to+one+billion+views+with+just+81+videos%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1681.1681.0.2550.1.1.0.0.0.0.43.43.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.9FJJzBZ8uFg

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be evidence that suggests that comments on a video can actually help it rank for certain keywords.

Google is now using language processing to understand what people are discussing. Comments criticizing the video could actually cause it to derank. Positive comments could cause it to rank. Keywords in comments help Google understand what the video is about.

Also, the people who comment on a video have their profile linked to in the comment section. High profile users with a lot of followers who comment on a video might pass that video a lot more link juice than an account with little activity.

Youtube comments are also a signal to help a video rank on Youtube. The more comments it gets, the more likely it is to rank.

As for the comments themselves, I haven't seen any examples of comments showing up directly in search results. They're more of a biproduct of the video and Google isn't ranking Youtube comments as content in their own merit, from what I've seen.

Comment: +1, I tried this and seems that author/comments won't show up. However, I did not wait for too long before checking the results.